# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't boot (radeon VCE init error -22)

Tags: 16.04, dell, amd-graphics, inspiron

I recently started using a pre-installed Ubuntu 16.04, Dell Inspiron 3567 laptop. I upgraded Ubuntu to 16.04.3. However now my laptop isn't booting. It shows `radeon 0000:01:00.0: VCE init error (-22)` and screen remains black with this error message forever. The laptop has an `AMD R5 M430` graphics card.

Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after trying multiple fresh installs of Ubuntu 16.04, it didn't materialize. I think `radeon R5 M430` graphics card is not compatible with 16.04. So finally I installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my machine, which as of now is working, but keeps giving error messages.